# Min Max Slider for two attributes not price

Tags: attributes, catalog, filter

We sell board games and need a filter that makes it possible to search for minimum players and maximum players.

When using built in filters we run into a logic problem, that maybe someone else was able to find a solution.

**Lets say you have to products.**

```
Product A

(min_players) 2 (max_players) 6

Product B <br>
(min_players) 3 (max_players) 5
```

If someone wants to list all products with (min_players) 3 and (max_players) 4 both should show up.

If someone wants to list all products with (min_players) 2 and (max_players) 5 only product A should show up.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a conceptual/software modelling question and not about Magento in particular.